# Sharing the link on the Wall pulls the old title and description somehow?

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I've got a question about my application posting on users' feed or even posting the link to the application/website itself, it pulls an old title/description for some reason.

As in, in the script used (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?name=...&description=...) to post the relevant title and description, even though they are updated on both the App and on my website, somehow the old version is being pulled and posted all over the place. If I put a link to my website where the app logic is, it pulls the old version somehow.

How can this be fixed, if at all?

Comment: The title and description are pulled from your page and not what you pass in

Comment: Those have been modified and it's still pulling the old data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook cache things. You can try one of the article URL in this debug tool, and see if you still see outdated results.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Typically, using this tool, will break the cache for the link you are testing it with.

Comment: Jesus... that was it?! I lost my mind over here trying to figure out what a heck is going on... and you were right, debugging did something to FB cache and now it pulled the right info. Thank you!